# Wipe files from an external hard drive but not empty space

Tags: files, dd, external-hdd, shred

I'm using the following command to wipe an external drive.

```
sudo shred -v -z -n 1 /dev/sdb
```

Is it possible to wipe an external drive of the files and not empty space? So it would overwrite where there is data but not where there isn't. This would save a lot of time when there aren't many files on the hard drive and I just want to empty the drive as fast as possible.

Not necessarily using the `shred` command.

I don't really mind about the security of the wipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `find` like so (to stay close to your original command)

`sudo find /mnt/sdb/ -type f -exec shred -v -n 1 {} +`

You should run it without `-exec` first so you can verify the list of files.

However, if you've already removed files using regular `rm`, or overwritten files by editing or copying them, those files may still exist in the "free" space of the filesystem. That's why usually you have to wipe the entire partition or at least the free space as well.